# application crashes when trying loadLibrary(), issue with pthread_create on 4.1.1?

Tags: multithreading, android-ndk, java-native-interface, cross-compiling, libc

I am trying to debug a crash with trying to load a library that I cross-compiled using System.loadLibrary().  I have been able to successfully load this library on any device running 4.0.4 (ICS), but it crashes on all of my devices running 4.1.1 (JB).  It seems to crash when running in to pthread_create() in libc:

```
10-01 14:25:34.173: D/dalvikvm(8215): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.gnychis.awmon/lib/libtshark.so 0x410fb430
10-01 14:25:34.181: A/libc(8215): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x5dfaa01c (code=2), thread 8232 (AsyncTask #1)
// And here is the end of the stack....
I/DEBUG   (  246):     #10  pc 0001263c  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+180)
```

Here is the much longer crash log that is involved showing the entire stack trace, and you will see it ends at libc and pthread_create:

```
D/dalvikvm(26364): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.gnychis.awmon/lib/libtshark.so 0x410a5ee0
F/libc    (26364): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x5dff301c (code=2), thread 27345 (AsyncTask #1)
D/AndroidRuntime(27404): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
I/DEBUG   (  246): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   (  246): Build fingerprint: 'd2uc-user 4.0.4 IMM76D I747UCALEM release-keys'
I/DEBUG   (  246): pid: 26364, tid: 27345, name: AsyncTask #1  >>> com.gnychis.awmon <<<
I/DEBUG   (  246): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 5dff301c
D/AndroidRuntime(27404): Shutting down VM
D/dalvikvm(27404): GC_CONCURRENT freed 99K, 88% free 498K/4096K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 7ms
I/AndroidRuntime(27404): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_3' failed
I/DEBUG   (  246):     r0 80000000  r1 02b1a000  r2 00000005  r3 5dff3000
I/DEBUG   (  246):     r4 40102894  r5 4010aaec  r6 00000000  r7 00000029
I/DEBUG   (  246):     r8 00000029  r9 5dff3000  sl 60871000  fp 02b1a000
I/DEBUG   (  246):     ip 00000005  sp 5d95ace0  lr 6004d1bb  pc 400ec6e0  cpsr 600d0030
I/DEBUG   (  246):     d0  61642f617461642f  d1  672e6d6f632f6174
I/DEBUG   (  246):     d2  612e73696863796e  d3  62696c2f6e6f6d77
I/DEBUG   (  246):     d4  00000000000e16f0  d5  000000000000695f
I/DEBUG   (  246):     d6  000000000002a715  d7  0000012f00000000
I/DEBUG   (  246):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  246):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  246):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  246):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  246):     d16 7420676e69797254  d17 6c2064616f6c206f
I/DEBUG   (  246):     d18 0063002f00610074  d19 0067002e006d006f
I/DEBUG   (  246):     d20 006800630079006e  d21 0061002e00730069
I/DEBUG   (  246):     d22 006e006f006d0077  d23 00620069006c002f
I/DEBUG   (  246):     d24 000000000000e16f  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  246):     d26 000000000000695f  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  246):     d28 000000000000695f  d29 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   (  246):     d30 0000000500000005  d31 0000000500000005
I/DEBUG   (  246):     scr 60000012
I/DEBUG   (  246): 
I/DEBUG   (  246): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   (  246):     #00  pc 000046e0  /system/bin/linker
I/DEBUG   (  246):     #01  pc 00005b6f  /system/bin/linker
I/DEBUG   (  246):     #02  pc 0004f73b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmLoadNativeCode(char const*, Object*, char**)+186)
I/DEBUG   (  246):     #03  pc 000662bd  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  246):     #04  pc 000274e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  246):     #05  pc 0002be08  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
I/DEBUG   (  246):     #06  pc 0005f9f5  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
I/DEBUG   (  246):     #07  pc 0005fa1f  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
I/DEBUG   (  246):     #08  pc 000545ab  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   (  246):     #09  pc 00012ee4  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
I/DEBUG   (  246):     #10  pc 0001263c  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+180)
```

The interesting thing is that if I use arm-eabi-objdump on the library, the address 1263c seems to be when it tries to do a pthread_clone:

```
$ arm-eabi-objdump -S /tmp/libc.so | grep 1263c
1263c:       ebffed71        bl      dc08 <__pthread_clone>
```

Does anyone have any insight as to why this would not be working on 4.1.1?  Also, why does my "Build fingerprint" at the top of my crash log show:

```
Build fingerprint: 'd2uc-user 4.0.4'
```

Could this be the root issue of why it's not running on 4.1.1?  I am using the newest NDK (r8b), with android-14 as the platform with the arm-eabi-4.4.3 toolchain.

Thanks so much for any help/guidance.

**EDIT:**  The majority of my crashes now seem to be happening in  ... did I lose a symbol here or something?

```
D/dalvikvm(11194): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.gnychis.awmon/lib/libtshark.so 0x4130fac8
F/libc    (11194): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x5df6b01c (code=2), thread 11230 (AsyncTask #1)
I/DEBUG   ( 7539): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   ( 7539): Build fingerprint: 'd2uc-user 4.0.4 IMM76D I747UCALEM release-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 7539): pid: 11194, tid: 11230, name: AsyncTask #1  >>> com.gnychis.awmon <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 7539): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 5df6b01c
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     r0 80000000  r1 02b1b000  r2 00000005  r3 5df6b000
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     r4 400e8894  r5 400f0aec  r6 00000000  r7 0000002a
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     r8 0000002a  r9 5df6b000  sl 607ea000  fp 02b1b000
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     ip 00000005  sp 5d8d2cd0  lr 5ffc5fff  pc 400d26e0  cpsr 600d0030
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     d0  61642f617461642f  d1  672e6d6f632f6174
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     d2  612e73696863796e  d3  62696c2f6e6f6d77
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     d4  00000000000e16f0  d5  000000000000695f
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     d6  000000000005a6e8  d7  0000012f00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     d16 7420676e69797254  d17 6c2064616f6c206f
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     d18 00000000006f7478  d19 0067002e006d006f
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     d20 006800630079006e  d21 0061002e00730069
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     d22 006e006f006d0077  d23 00620069006c002f
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     d24 000000000000e16f  d25 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     d26 000000000000695f  d27 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     d28 000000000000695f  d29 0000000000000000
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     d30 0000000d0000000d  d31 0000000d0000000d
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     scr 60000012
I/DEBUG   ( 7539): 
I/DEBUG   ( 7539): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     #00  pc 000046e0  /system/bin/linker
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     #01  pc 00005b6f  /system/bin/linker
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     #02  pc 0004f73b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmLoadNativeCode(char const*, Object*, char**)+186)
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     #03  pc 000662bd  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     #04  pc 00027524  /system/lib/libdvm.so
I/DEBUG   ( 7539):     #05  pc 000fedd8  <unknown>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Android JNI: Calling System.loadLibrary() causes SEGV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184579/android-jni-calling-system-loadlibrary-causes-segv). Does your native library have JNI_OnLoad()? If this function calls JNI functions, try to call it from the main (UI) thread.

Comment: hmmmm, it seems like in that thread the library actually loaded though.  Mine never gets to that point, so I don't think it will actually end up calling JNI_OnLoad().  I can give it a shot though...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my toolchain was too old.  I upgraded to the newer arm-eabi toolchain in the AOSP project, and the library links just fine now!