# JNIEnv->FindClass() fails in JNI_OnLoad

Tags: android, java-native-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I load my own Java class in C on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838397/how-do-i-load-my-own-java-class-in-c-on-android)
>   [Application works in debug / run from Eclipse, but .APK gives .classNotFoundException when parsing XML layout that contains a custom View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079585/application-works-in-debug-run-from-eclipse-but-apk-gives-classnotfoundexce)

In Android, I am accessing a native C library, by doing:

```
System.loadLibrary("testlib");
```

To load a native library.
In the JNI_OnLoad() function, it is trying to find a Java glue code class:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
        JNIEnv *env;
        jclass k;
        jint r;

        r = vm->GetEnv ((void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_4);
        k = env->FindClass ("com/test/android/aclass");
```

The FindClass() fails, and throws a NoClassDefFoundError exception.
Any idea why I cannot see my Java class from my C code?

I use this same library in another test application, and it works (so I am confident that the library works).  I don't see why one app can find the java class, while the other cannot.

Comment: Where is the `com/test/android/aclass` class defined? In the project itself or in a jar file that is mixed in?

Comment: Good article -- thanks for the link.  But in the end found my problem was proguard.cfg.  When I disabled proguard its now working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.
My clue was that it would run fine if I ran it through eclipse, and only had this problem when I created a .apk file.

I found the solution here: [Application works in debug / run from Eclipse, but .APK gives .classNotFoundException when parsing XML layout that contains a custom View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079585/application-works-in-debug-run-from-eclipse-but-apk-gives-classnotfoundexce)